# Magic [Post Id] formatting should give useful link text for tag wikis/excerpts

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

Currently, if you try to use the magic

```sql
Id AS [Post Link]
```

formatting for a post that is a tag wiki or a tag wiki excerpt (i.e. `PostTypeId IN (4, 5)`), you get a link that goes to the right place but for which the text is "unknown". You can see this behavior at [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/189405).

It would be nice if these magic links would instead say something like "code-conversion wiki excerpt", if this isn't something that's too difficult to implement.